# How to print UTF-8 correctly using XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8, libxml2

I wrote a script which converts a hash into an XML and returns the result of the `toString` function from [`XML::LibXML::Document`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod). It seems impossible for me to print the result (the string) without crippling the UTF-8 characters in the XML document.

I tried using `binmode` for STDOUT and using/avoiding `setEncoding` for the XML document. Neither worked as I expected.

The only "solution" for this was to disable the XML declaration with `$XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;` or to `decode` the string before returning it to the script which wants to print it.

I just don't get the part with this declaration line. I could even return the string (with this declaration line) to my second script, write it to a file without any crippled characters and got crippled characters if I print directly to STDOUT. As mentioned above I even tried using `binmode`.

So, what's wrong with `toString` or printing an XML to STDOUT in general? Am I missing something? If needed I can provide some code of course.

In this specific case I just switched from `XML::Simple` to `XML::LibXML` and it worked fine with `XML::Simple`. I know `XML::Simple` is not that great; I'm just curious why it's working fine and `XML::LibXML` kept me busy the whole day.

---

This is a sample of the code I'm using. To be honest, this snippet works like a charm and I'm still struggling to find the difference to my real script, which I obviously can't post here. But to show you what I'm doing this might be ok:

create_xml.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package create_xml;

use XML::LibXML;
use utf8;

sub convertHash
{
    my ($hash) = @_;

    my $xmlDoc = XML::LibXML::Document->new();
    $xmlDoc->setEncoding('UTF-8');

    my $xmlRoot = $xmlDoc->createElement('TestXML');

    foreach my $key (keys %$hash)
    {
        my $wert = $hash->{$key};
        my $element = $xmlDoc->createElement($key);
        $element->appendTextNode($wert);
        $xmlRoot->appendChild($element);
    }

    my $wsStatusElement = $xmlDoc->createElement('FixedElement');
    $wsStatusElement->appendTextNode(123);
    $xmlRoot->appendChild($wsStatusElement);

    $xmlDoc->setDocumentElement($xmlRoot);

    open(XML, '>', 'test1.xml');
        print XML $xmlDoc->toString(1);
    close(XML);

    return $xmlDoc->toString(1);
}

1;
```

print_xml.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib '.';
use create_xml;
use utf8;

my %testhash;
$testhash->{'A'} = 15;
$testhash->{'B'} = 'abc';
$testhash->{'C'} = 'äöüä';
$testhash->{'D'} = '€';

my $xml = create_xml::convertHash($testhash);

open(XML, '>', 'test2.xml');
    print XML $xml;
close(XML);

print $xml;
```

With this scripts both written xml-files are fine, but the output of the last print is broken. My € looks like this `<D>â�¬</D>`. As mentioned before, this snippet is **working**. I'll edit my question later on, after I found the difference.

---

I finally managed to find the problem. I used a perlmodule which says `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`. So why is this corrupting my characters for printing, but not for writing to files? I'm still very confused and feel like I'm missing something. Is this the part, where the already utf8 encoded characters get encoded twice? And is there an option to reset this?

Comment: I think we need to see an example of input XML and Perl code that produces this problem. A better description of the "crippling" would also help. What platform are you working on, and how are you examining the output of your program?

Comment: I attached a snippet, but right now this snippet is working. That's pretty confusing to me and I'll investigate this further. Maybe someone can already see, what may be wrong with my code ;)

Answer (score 3):

It works for me.

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -MXML::LibXML -we '
    my $xml =q{<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?><r>ěščřž</r>};
    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);
    binmode STDOUT, "encoding(UTF-8)";
    print $doc->findvalue("r"), "\n";
'
ěščřž
```

With `toString`, you need to use [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode)'s `decode`:

```
print decode("utf-8", $doc->toString), "\n";
```

Comment: The result of `toString` should be fine if printed directly to a device expecting UTF-8. It's just not much use as a character string within Perl

Answer (score 3):

`$doc->toString` returns a string that's already encoded. The encoding used is the one set by `$doc->setEncoding` and returned by `$doc->actualEncoding`. By default, this is UTF-8 for new documents, or the original encoding for existing documents.

So, all you have to do is print the output of `$doc->toString` to STDOUT without first adding encoding layers to STDOUT.

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use XML::LibXML qw( );
   my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new(1.0, "UTF-8");
   my $root = $doc->createElement("root");
   $root->appendText("\x{2660}");
   $doc->setDocumentElement($root);
   print $doc->toString();
' | od -c
0000000   <   ?   x   m   l       v   e   r   s   i   o   n   =   "   1
0000020   "       e   n   c   o   d   i   n   g   =   "   U   T   F   -
0000040   8   "   ?   >  \n   <   r   o   o   t   > 342 231 240   <   /
0000060   r   o   o   t   >  \n
0000066
```

It's hard to tell what problem you are experiencing because you didn't provide a demonstration of your problem.

The most likely problem is that you are passing encoded text to XML::LibXML when you should be passing decoded text.

Another less likely possibility is that you've run afoul of the [bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=115190) from which `appendText` and other methods of adding text to a document suffer. You can work around that bug by "upgrading" your text.

```
   sub _u($) { my $s = shift; utf8::upgrade($s); $s }

   $root->appendText("\x{C9}ric");       # Buggy
   $root->appendText(_u("\x{C9}ric"));   # Ok
```